# how to load spring bean from imported maven dependency without importing the context.xml

Tags: spring-integration

I want to load Spring Bean at startup, which are present in imported maven dependency. Is there a way we can do this without actually importing the context.xml from injected dependency jar ?

I tried @EnableAutoConfiguration, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

M-m-m. No choice. Nothing will appear in the Spring application context if don't tell it to do that.

If your dependency have only `context.xml`, so nothing magical unless `@Import`.

The `@EnableAutoConfiguration` works only for those who are `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration` registered.

See `spring.factories` in the `spring-boot-autoconfigure/META-INFO`.

And right: read more Spring Boot Docs.

So, if you don't want to `@Import`, you can write some `@Configuration` (e.g. `MyAutoConfiguration`) with that `@Import` and add `spring.factories` to your any jar with the content like:

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=org.my.proj.autoconfigure.MyAutoConfiguration
```

Comment: i have a @Configuration bean in maven-project A where i define xxx bean.

Comment: ??? And? How about everything else what I have pointed out? Sorry, but this your comment useless and adds more noise than help.

Comment: i already have a **@Configuration** class in maven-project A where i define xxx bean.   Now i include maven-project A as a maven dependency in another maven-project B. Is there a way I can ref XXX bean of maven-project A without explicitly importing the **@Configuration** class in web.xml

Comment: I'm not sure why do you find my answer as non-relevant to this comment, too... Or you use `@Import` or do that over `spring.factories`, if you are based on the Spring Boot. Nothing more.

Comment: i added spring.factories org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration key-value pair, but it still throws error NoSuchBeanDefinitionException.

Comment: It may work if i add **@Configuration** classname in web.xml contextConfigLocation of the project using this maven dependency. I am looking for a better option, where they dont do any change except for just importing the maven dependency.Want to avoid any change in web.xml

Comment: Well, then we need to know how do you load Spring Boot there.

Comment: The calling application is simple web app exposing JAX RS service. And this is a separate component which has JAX RS filter and Spring Integration interceptor to intercept all spring-integration channel and JAX RS request/response. The calling application include this maven dependency.

Comment: well i see this line in stacktrace - Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration$JerseyWebApplicationInitializer@4b7e7af2]

Comment: That is standard servlet initializer scan. Nothing special from Boot perspective. Dig farther and read rtfm!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a bean in your application and extend the beans to be loaded.

Example (I have used it to externalize rabbitmq bindings definitions):

External:

```
package com.bpedroso.rabbitmq.beans;

import org.springframework.amqp.core.Binding;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.BindingBuilder;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.DirectExchange;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.FanoutExchange;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class CustomerMQBinding {

@Bean
public Queue myQueue() { ... }

@Bean
public Queue myDlq() { ... }

@Bean
public DirectExchange myExchange() { ... }

@Bean
FanoutExchange myDlx() { ... }

/*
 * Bindings
 */
@Bean
Binding bindingMyrQueue(final Queue myQueue, final DirectExchange myExchange) { ... }

@Bean
Binding bindingMyDlq(final Queue myDlq, final FanoutExchange myDlx) { ... }
}
```

Current project:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import com.bpedroso.rabbitmq.beans.CustomerMQBinding;;

@Configuration
public class MyCustomerBindingMQBeans extends CustomerMQBinding {
}
```